# Authorization and execution of the link

Tags: php, rest-api, curl

I'm connecting a custom payment gateway to the "Paid Member Subscriptions" plugin. I already have the payment process ready and redirected to the payment operator's website. After authorization, the operator takes me back to the subpage with thanks for the payment. I'm looking for a way to change my subscription status automatically..

The link in the following format is responsible for activating the subscription:

https://website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=pms-payments-page&pms-action=complete_payment&payment_id=100&_wpnonce=a0920fd1e0

I can get the variable from the last payment and set the answer payment_id= I can also get the correct wpnonce so it's not a problem.

The main problem is that the link requires authorization because the status change is done in the wp admin panel.

The question is whether the authorization can be done using the REST API and then somehow execute this link in the background using curl or otherwise?